# Равность обьектов класса в ООП

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

```
class Point:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

Как сделать что б обьекты класса были равны при условии что координаты х(или у) равны?
В итоте должно быть так:

```
>>> a = Point(1, 2)
>>> b = Point(1, 3)
>>> c = Point(2, 2)
>>> a == b
True
>>> a == c
False
```

Comment: `def __eq__(self, other):
    return other.x == self.x`
Так должно бить?

Comment: зачем тебе делать равными неравные объекты? Не проще координаты сравнить?

Comment: мне нужно чтоб равность испольналась при моем условии

Comment: @codename0082016 он в примере указал равность только по X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подходит?

```
In [11]: class Example:
    ...:     def __init__(self, x, y):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...:         self.y = y
    ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
    ...:         if self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y:
    ...:             return True
    ...:         return False

In [12]: A = Example(1, 1)

In [13]: B = Example(1, 1)

In [14]: A == B
Out[14]: True

In [15]: a = Example(1, 2)

In [16]: A == a
Out[16]: False
```

Comment: да, меня больше интересовал синтаксис и название метода __eq__(я его не знал)

Comment: @lalalala если ответ вам  подходит - нажмите галочку слева.

Comment: ну на вопрос код ответ не дает, поставьте в 6 строке то что я в коменте написал(возможно кто-то тоже будет ответ на такой вопрос искать, а ответ не правильний, он только мне подходит)

Comment: но ответ на вопрос неправильний)
ответ подошел мне но он не отвечает на вопрос

Comment: @lalalala Что вас еще интересует? По моему я дал вам ответ, если нет - дополните или переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: там написано
равность должна быть когда равны координаты Х, а не Х и У
 `def __eq__(self, other):
     return other.x == self.x`
так правильно

Comment: @lalalala Вы серьёзно? Я указал условие для примера. Если это шутка - без комментариев.

Answer (score 3):

Для определения остальных операций сравнения, кроме `__eq__`, удобно воспользоватся [`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).
Достаточно определить лишь один метод, например `__lt__`, остальные создаст [`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x or self.y < other.y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

A = Point(1, 1)
B = Point(1, 1)
C = Point(2, 1)
print(A == B, A < B, A >= B, B <= C)  # True False True True
```

Еще есть [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), который все это умеет сам

```
from collections import namedtuple

point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
A = point(1, 1)
B = point(1, 1)
C = point(2, 1)
print(A == B, A < B, A >= B, B <= C)  # True False True True
```