# Сравнение объектов на python

Tags: python, структуры-данных

Есть 2 объекта. Поэлементное сравнение обеспечивает равенство (т.е. сравнение каждого элемента с каждым, `x.min_x` с `y.min_x`, `x.min_y` с `x.min_y` и т.д.). Если сравнить на равенство с помощью оператора `==`, тогда возникнет они не будут равными. Все действия проводятся в рамках *pyCharm*

```
x = Rectangle(min_x=1, max_x=4, min_y=0, max_y=3)
y = Rectangle(min_x=1, max_x=4, min_y=0, max_y=3)
a = x.max_y == y.max_y  # True
a = x.max_x == y.max_x  # True
a = x.min_x == y.min_x  # True
a = x.min_y == y.min_y  # True
a = x == y  # False
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: У вас не списки, а объекты же, нет?

Comment: @Flowneee поправил. Спасибо

Comment: И? У вас все еще 2 объекта. То, что внутри они представлены списком или чем либо еще, не отменяет того, что это 2 объекта. А по умолчанию 2 объекта сравниваются никак не по содержимому, а по ссылкам на эти объекты.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python не умеет сравнивать пользовательские объекты по умолчанию — ведь действительно, изнутри классы могут быть устроены намного сложнее, чем прямолинейные наборы значений. Их сравнение в таком случае может включать в себя сопоставление не всех переменных, а только некоторых, а иногда с ними для этого ещё нужно совершить какие-то действия. И это не говоря о том, что иногда нам может потребоваться сравнивать объекты разных классов.

Так что в общем случае два *различных* экземпляра пользовательских классов всегда будут считаться неравными друг другу.
Чтобы проверить это, сначала определим класс для наших объектов:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y):
        self.min_x, self.min_y = min_x, min_y
        self.max_x, self.max_y = max_x, max_y
```

Попробуем на всякий случай сравнить два произвольных объекта, не имеющих ничего общего:

```
foo = Rectangle(0, 0, 42, 42)
bar = Rectangle(4, 8, 15, 16)

print(foo == bar) # False
```

Пока что, в общем-то, ничего неожиданного. Теперь посмотрим, что получится при сравнении экземпляров, обладающих идентичными наборами атрибутов:

```
baz = Rectangle(0, 0, 42, 42)
# казалось бы, этот объект ничем не отличается от первого
print(foo == baz) # False
```

Вопреки ожиданиям, при попытке сравнения мы всё ещё получаем `False` — оператор `==` даже не пытается смотреть на атрибуты объектов.

Кажется, что с чем бы мы не пытались сравнить экземпляр пользовательского класса, результат всегда будет отрицательным. Это близко к правде, но с одним небольшим исключением:

```
print(foo == foo) # True
```

Каждый объект по умолчанию равен сам себе — то есть, вообще говоря, функция сравнения полностью эквивалентна проверке `object1 is object2`. Этим можно пользоваться, хотя всё-таки лучше делать это напрямую через `is`.

Ну и если вспомнить специфику присваивания в питоне, становится понятно, как работает следующий случай:

```
quux = foo
print(quux == foo, quux is foo) # True True
```

Мы не создали новый объект, а просто привязали имя quux к старому объекту foo, который как был один, так и остался. И сам себе он, как и раньше, эквивалентен.

Теперь о том, как эту ситуацию можно изменить.

Возможное решение «в лоб» — взять словари всех атрибутов объектов и сравнить их напрямую — а словари считаются равными тогда и только тогда, когда все их ключи и значения попарно равны:

```
print(bar.__dict__ == baz.__dict__) # True
```

Однако подобный прямой доступ к служебным переменным извне без веского повода считается очень некрасивым и «непитоновским», тем более, что полностью это проблему не решает — если среди значений атрибутов будут не только простые сущности, но и, например, экземпляры вложенных классов, сравнение снова не сработает как надо. Да и запись такого способа очень неудобная и громоздкая сама по себе.

«Правильное» решение в подобных случаях — определить в классе метод [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), который задаёт взаимодействие объектов с оператором `==`. Метод должен принимать на вход два аргумента `self` и `other` и возвращать `True`, если объекты равны и `False` — если они не равны. Если объекты таких типов вообще не сравнимы друг с другом, нужно возвращать `NotImplemented` — увидев его, интерпретатор попробует использовать метод `__eq__` из второго аргумента, ну а если и он вернёт `NotImplemented`, результат сведётся к `False`.

Переопределим наш класс так, чтобы при вызове `__eq__` попарно сравнивались координаты прямоугольников:

```
class Rectangle(object):
        ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # сравнение двух прямоугольников
        if isinstance(other, Rectangle):
            return (self.min_x == other.min_x and
                         self.min_y == other.min_y and
                         self.max_x == other.max_x and
                         self.max_y == other.max_y)
        # иначе возвращаем NotImplemented
        return NotImplemented

foo = Rectangle(0, 0, 42, 42)
bar = Rectangle(4, 8, 15, 16)

print(foo == bar) # всё ещё False

baz = Rectangle(0, 0, 42, 42)
print(foo == baz) # True

print(foo == 10) # False
```

Метод `__eq__` добавляет нашему классу немало гибкости — объекты могут иметь атрибуты, не участвующие в процессе сравнения (к примеру, уникальные имена), да и сам алгоритм при необходимости можно усложнять: скажем, у прямоугольников можно сравнивать только форму, вне зависимости от расположения на плоскости.

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y, name=None):
        ...
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Rectangle):
            return (self.max_x - self.min_x == other.max_x - other.min_x and
                         self.max_y - self.min_y == other.max_y - other.min_y)
        return NotImplemented

print(Rectangle(4, 8, 15, 16, 'spam') == Rectangle(14, 18, 25, 26, 'eggs')) # True
```

Или и вовсе можно сравнивать прямоугольники только по площади, причём не только друг с другом, но и, скажем, с треугольниками или даже с числовыми значениями:

```
from math import sqrt

class Rectangle(object):
        ...
    def area(self):
        return (self.max_x - self.min_x)*(self.max_y - self.min_y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (Rectangle, Triangle)):
            return self.area() == other.area()
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return self.area() == other
        return NotImplemented

class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y, c_x, c_y):
    # задаётся координатами трёх вершин
        self.a_x, self.a_y = a_x, a_y
        self.b_x, self.b_y = b_x, b_y
        self.c_x, self.c_y = c_x, c_y
        # сразу посчитаем длины сторон
        self.ab = sqrt((a_x - b_x)**2 + (a_y - b_y)**2)
        self.bc = sqrt((b_x - c_x)**2 + (b_y - c_y)**2)
        self.ca = sqrt((c_x - a_x)**2 + (c_y - a_y)**2)

    def area(self):
        p = (self.ab + self.bc + self.ca)/2
        return sqrt(p * (p - self.ab) * (p - self.bc) * (p - self.ca))

    def __eq__(self, other):
       ...

print(Rectangle(57, 179, 59, 185) == Rectangle(-100, 4, -96, 7)) # True
print(Rectangle(1, 4, 9, 7) == Triangle(0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 0)) # True
```

Строго говоря, для треугольников можно было вообще не определять метод `__eq__` — для межклассового сравнения достаточно того, чтобы он присутствовал хоть в каком-то из классов. Но в общем случае всё равно стоит прописывать его и там, и там. Во-первых, это позволит, если понадобится, сравнивать треугольники между собой. Во-вторых, при обработке сравнения интерпретатор может в первую очередь попытаться использовать `__eq__` как из первого объекта, так и из второго (зависит от конкретных параметров интерпретации), и наличие обоих методов немного ускорит обработку.

Вот как-то так. Подробнее про `__eq__`, обратный ему `__ne__` и прочие специальные классовые методы можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: +1 за *"в общем случае два различных экземпляра пользовательских классов всегда будут считаться неравными друг другу."* Стоит упомянуть, что для неизменяемых объектов с пользовательским `__eq__` методом, стоит ещё соответствующий `__hash__` определить. Ещё вместо создания своих классов, можно готовые использовать: `collections.namedtuple`, `typing.NamedTuple`, `types.SimpleNamespace`, классы из `attrs` пакета, в которых `__eq__` уже определен ([пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653719/23044)).

Answer (score 4):

У вас два разных объекта с одинаковым содержимым. Если хотите, чтобы сравнивалось не равенство ссылок на объекты, а равенство их содержимого, вам стоит переопределить как минимум метод [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).

Answer (score 1):

[`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) и [`магические методы`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-special-method).

Любая операция, применимая к объекту, обязательно "требует" наличия у объекта, метода, соответствующего операции. Такой метод называют `специальным` или `магическим`. Некоторые `магические методы` определены для объектов по умолчанию, остальные необходимо определять самому.

Например, чтобы объект вел себя как функция, т.е. вызывался `()`: `myObj()`, то в `myObj` должен быть метод `__call__`.

Чтобы сравнить объекты, оператором `>`: `myObj1 > myObj2`, должен быть метод `__gt__`.

И так с любой, применимой к объекту операцией.

Для операторов сравнения, чтобы не определять все возможные операции сравнения, удобно использовать `total_ordering`, как в [примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677668/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f/677711#677711).